# this activity not working in android studio but same working in eclipse editor

Tags: android, android-studio

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sar);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/SAR.gif");


The above url is not loading
    splashTimer = new Timer();
    splashTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SARActivity.this.finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(SARActivity.this, SARActivity.class));
        }
    }, DELAY);
    scheduled = true;

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (scheduled)
        splashTimer.cancel();
    splashTimer.purge();
}
```

it is not working///means it is webview is not loading specified url
i have added permissions in manifest file before application ...but same code is working in eclipse but not in android studio...simply it is giving timed out error

Comment: Did you add the proper permissions to AndroidManifest? Keep in mind that if your Target SDK is 23 or higher, you will need to add them at runtime as well.

Comment: did you check your `url` is working or not ??